# AngularJS: $parse transform numeric string to number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my case, I have a directive which reads the value from attr.

For example:

```
<span my-id="{{model.id}}"></span>
<span my-id="1234567890"></span>
<span my-id="0000000000"></span>
```

In this directive I `$watch` this attr:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function(){
        return $parse($attrs.myId)($scope);
    },
    function(val){
        ...
    }
)
```

The problem is, in the case of '0000000000' - the `val` passed to function is number 0. So, there is an input string - `'0000000000'` and output `0` in `$parse`. Is there any way to bypass this? The main reason for me to use `$parse` function is different sources of id. It could be an interpolation or plain string.

Thx.

Comment: like this :`<span my-id="'0000000000'"></span>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use interpolation or just plain-string on a random base.

- You could define an attribute for interpolated values and another one for plain-strings eg: `my-id` for plain strings and `dyn-id` for interpolated-ones.
- Or just pass strings that will get interpolated :

  ```
  <span my-id="'0000000000'"></span>
  ```

Comment: You're right. Not tested it completely, but changing `$parse` to `$parse("'" + attr.myId + "'")(scope);` worked. Thx. As I can see, it'll work in a case of interpolation as well.

Comment: Nope, your solution is the only way afterall.